# TCPClient seems to not maintain a keep-alive connection, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter, tcp, tcpclient

I have the following code using the TcpClient

```
byte[] encbuff = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("username" + ":" + "password");
        string follow = "track=soccer,twitter";
        byte[] encode_follow = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(follow);

        using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
        {
            string requestString = "POST /1/statuses/filter.json HTTP/1.1\r\n";
            requestString += "Host: stream.twitter.com\r\n";
            requestString += "User-Agent: www.site.com\r\n";
            requestString += "Referer: http://www.site.com\r\n";
            requestString += "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
            requestString += "Authorization: " + "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(encbuff) + "\r\n";
            requestString += "Content-length: " + follow.Length + "\r\n";
            requestString += "Connection: keep-alive\r\n";
            requestString += "\r\n";
            requestString += follow;
            requestString += "\r\n\r\n";

            client.Connect("stream.twitter.com", 80);
            //client.ReceiveTimeout = 100;
            using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
            {
                // Send the request.
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
                writer.Write(requestString);
                writer.Flush();

                // Process the response.

                    StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(stream);

                    while (!rdr.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(rdr.ReadLine());
                        Console.WriteLine("IS end: " + rdr.EndOfStream.ToString());
                    }
                }

        }
```

What happens though is that the  Console.WriteLine(rdr.ReadLine());  line will print out statuses for a few seconds than it would stop + not hit the break point there anymore, even though it's still connected.

What it should be doing is continuing to write the statuses in the console, since it's a keep-alive connection and the 'Twitter' keyword gets mentioned a few times every few seconds continuously.

Any ideas what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Using a `TcpClient` for the HTTP protocol seems an overkill. Have you ever considered using a `WebClient`?

Comment: Well, when I use a webclient or httpwebrequest with a keepalive connection, the stream always closes after a certain period and I have to close the connection and reopen. I think TcpClient is the only one that supports keeping a connection open and reading from the stream indefinitely.

Comment: I'm successfully reading a Twitter feed with WebClient. I use WebClient.OpenReadAsync and read using a StreamReader. I haven't noticed the connection closing on its own so far.

Comment: When I use WebClient, especially with follow... what happens is that for that time period there won't be any items and so responseStream.EndOfStream will be true, thus closing the stream. I have to reconnect to get a new responseStream.

Comment: @rksprst, `WebClient` supports streaming. See my response for an example.

Comment: Thanks guys... I did some more checking and it turns out the prob was with the username/password used with authentication. Seems Twitter was authenticating it but not returning results. When I used another account to authenticate with, it worked fine (both the TCPClient code and my old HttpWebRequest client code).

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            client.OpenReadCompleted += (sender, e) =>
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(e.Result))
                {
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        // TODO: feed this to your favorite JSON parser
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
                    }
                }
            };
            client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?track=soccer,twitter"));
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Should make things easier.

Comment: Thanks, your code actually had the same problem - which is how I figured out what's wrong. Turns out it was a problem with the streaming permissions for one account. I tried with another account and it was fine.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by streaming permissions?